# How to Integrate PhpGrid with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpgrid

I am trying to integrate Phpgrid with laravel 4.
I tried putting it in the vendor module and did composer dump-autload, but it is throwing errors.  I also tried putting phpgrid folder in the library and then autoload it, but nothing seems to be working.  I keep getting this 
PHP Fatal error:  Could not convert the script from the detected encoding "UTF-8" to a compatible encoding in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php on line 118
error when i do composer dump-autoload.
  Can somebody let me know the steps.  I browsed for resources, looks like not much resources are available about this kind of integration.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This help me: [setting up phpChart in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130925/setting-up-phpchart-in-laravel/25155428#25155428) phpGrid should work the same way. Basically you need to make sure the SERVER_ROOT path is set correctly.

If you are not sure, you can use the following script. It generates the correct corresponding SERVER_ROOT value based on your current executing script.

```
define('SERVER_ROOT', str_replace(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])),'', str_replace('\\', '/',dirname(__FILE__))));
```

Comment: There you go. Official from phpGrid:
http://phpgrid.com/example/phpgrid-laravel-5-twitter-bootstrap-3-integration/