# setting up phpChart in laravel

Tags: php, charts, laravel-4, amazon-ec2, composer-php

Environment:Amazon EC2. Ubuntu x64. (GD library installed)
I'm recently using phpChart for graph and report in laravel framework.
I'm stuck at the beginning stage.

Here's what I've done.

- 1.Unzip the contents in phpChart_Lite to /var/www/app/libraries/phpChart.
- 2.Edit composer.json and add :

  ```
  "autoload": {
      "classmap": [
          ...
          "app/libraries"
      ]
  },
  ```
- 3.run:composer dump-autoload
- 4.modify conf.php in phpChart_Lite

  ```
  define('SCRIPTPATH',app_path().'/libraries/phpChart_Lite/');
  ```

Here's my test page code:

```
<?php
require_once(app_path()."/libraries/phpChart_Lite/conf.php");
$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array(array(11, 9, 5, 12, 14)),'basic_chart');
$pc->draw();
?>
```

ps.my app_path() is verified by "echo app_path()" and it is "/var/www/app".

Here's my error message:

```
Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/public//var/www/app/libraries/phpChart_Lite//conf.php' 
(include_path='/var/www/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

Comment: I've set the permission 777 to /libraries and it's sub-directories. the path in the error message is definitely wrong:"/var/www/public//var/www/app/library". But my code is right. That's what bothers me most.

Comment: for more information. the error occurs on the file:/var/www/app/libraries/phpChart_Lite/server/cls_conf.php

Comment: I saw double slashes BEFORE conf.php in the error message. That would likely be the cause to Failed opening required".
Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/public//var/www/app/libraries/phpChart_Lite//conf.php'

Comment: My guess is that the SCRIPTPATH is defined as "/var/www/app/libraries/phpChart_Lite/" modified by me. Thus, I consider this required path is written by phpchart as "WebsiteDirectory + SCRIPTPATH + conf.php". And my approach works. :D

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of try-and-error, I somehow found the root cause, I guess. 
There are actually two main issue there. And here's my solution.

1.For my issue explained in the very first post.
In the conf.php file in phpChart_Lite folder. The SCRIPTPATH is somehow prefixed with /var/www/public.

However, in my apache2.conf file states the directory to be /var/www. Regardless this prefix, I use a absolute path for SCRIPTPATH. The following modification works for me:

```
    define('SCRIPTPATH','../app/libraries/phpChart_Lite/');
```

The error was gone. But the second issue appears, that is the chart doesn't show up.
Open the Chrome Developer Tool(press F12). On the 'Console' tab, I found error 404 for loading phpChar_Lite/js. One of the error messages as following:

```
   http://myip/app/libraries/phpChart_Lite/js/highlighter/styles/zenburn.css
```

As the design of Laravel, only public folder can be access by external request.
So I got second issue. And here's my solution.(not a secured method)

2.Move the phpChart_Lite to public folder. Modify the code of test page:

```
    include_once(public_path()."/phpChart_Lite/conf.php");
```

Modify the conf.php in public/phpChart_Lite:

```
    define('SCRIPTPATH','phpChart_Lite/');
```

Everything's just fine now.

If you consider phpChart is too complicate to configure with, you might want to try pChart2.0.
It doesn't require much setting. But the graph is terribly ugly.

I prefer phpChart for it's graph and function calls, though the setting is a little complicated and not laravel friendly.